Disabled Chips in Flutter Form Builder Have the Wrong Style
Besides October and November the rest is supposed to be greyed out.

Here is my code:
        FormBuilderFilterChip<Month>(
          name: 'months',
          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
          ),
          maxChips: 2,
          spacing: 8,
          runSpacing: 8,
          options: Month.values.where((e) => e != Month.unknown).map((e) {
            return FormBuilderChipOption(
              value: e,
              child: Text(e.toString()),
            );
          }).toList(),
          validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose(validators),
          initialValue: List.of(approxDate?.months ?? {}),
        )

